# What is the easiest way to make Cloud Function inactive/paused?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have my cloud function that is triggered by Firestore event. For security reasons I need to manually enable/disable this function several times per day. So every time I have to edit and switch on and off its Firestore trigger event through the cloud functions console.

Is there an easier way to "pause" cloud function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing built into the Cloud Functions platform to pause functions. For demos where I need something like this, I typically store a flag whether the function is enabled in my database (Firestore or Realtime Database) and then read that value as the first operation in my code.