# Disable cloud function through billing alert?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-billing

I am meeting the same issue and found this answer[1] [What is the easiest way to make Cloud Function inactive/paused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564846/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-make-cloud-function-inactive-paused)

But in this case although I can save a bool value in firebase rtdb, but since the cloud function has to keep active to check this bool value, just the rest part of this cloud function will be inactive, the cost exists already. Is there any better solution, such as setting a billing alert and then connect to pub/sub? I just have no idea how to disable the cloud function totally to save the cost that user triggers the cloud function.

here is the some code although I am not sure if it works:

```
const cloudfunctions = google.cloudfunctions('v1');
exports.disableFunctionOnBillingAlert = functions.pubsub.topic('wellWavel_remove_cloudFunction_whenCostTooHigh').onPublish(async (message, context) => {
  const messageData = message.json;

 
  if (messageData && messageData.costAmount && messageData.budgetAmount && messageData.costAmount >= messageData.budgetAmount) {
    
    const authClient = await google.auth.getClient({
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
    });
    google.options({ auth: authClient });

    const functionName = `projects/wellwave-cfc72/locations/us-central1/functions/incrementQuota`;
    try {
      await cloudfunctions.projects.locations.functions.patch({
        name: functionName,
        updateMask: 'status',
        requestBody: {
          status: 'INACTIVE',
        },
      });
      console.log(`Cloud Function ${functionName} has been disabled.`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Failed to disable Cloud Function ${functionName}:`, error);
      throw new Error(`Failed to disable Cloud Function ${functionName}: ${error}`);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to control the execution of the function through env variables? Connect billing alert to a pubsub event where a function would listen and update your env variable of your main cloud function to blocked or so. The function wouldnt be fully disabled as this is impossible but as execution times goes down, your cost would be minor. Maybe you can also change the spec of the function.

Comment: if your application/users have a certain group or use service account to trigger the cloud function, maybe you can set a simple logic within a function in response to an alert event  to disable the service account or the groups permissions ( cloud invoker ).

Comment: Hi Fahed thx for the reply, I guess your solution is similiar to save a bool value to firebase, I try to find a way to make cloud funtion inactive, which Frank said impossible...maybe just above solution works, or temporarily delete the cloud function, thus preventing users from maliciously continuing to call the

Comment: The only way to disable the cloud function is to remove its trigger, which (given that you use Firebase) is easiest to do by publishing (with `firebase deploy`) without the `disableFunctionOnBillingAlert` function present.  Also see the video series [Cap your Firebase spending](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmK1tiMBeKA0iDMPDCJKM-5), which uses the billing alert to remove the billing instrument (i.e. the credit card).